# How to get this dom tree using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create an html code like that:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class="firstChild"></div>
    <div class="secondChild"></div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='firstChild'></div>
    <div class="secondChild"></div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='firstChild'></div>
    <div class="secondChild"></div>
</div>
```

using this :

```
  var content = '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        content += '<div class="parent">';
            content += '<div class="firstChild"></div>';
            content += '<div class="secondChild"></div>';
        content += '</div>';
    }
    $('.conainer').html(content);
```

but I get something else like:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='firstChild'></div>
    <div class="secondChild">
        <div class='parent'>
        <div class='firstChild'></div>
        <div class="secondChild"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this and get the right dom tree?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your script. There is no way you are getting any output.

Comment: use different quotation marks or escape them with backslashes. your example works for me.

Comment: @trincot , I edited the code , I replaced the ' with " and added   $('.conainer').html(content);

Comment: `$('.conainer'),html(content);` is not right (comma?). Where is the container element? Please provide a script with which we can *reproduce* the problem, as the code after fixing the trivial errors in the question works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you got the single quotes misplaced,

try using some double quotes too, to avoid breaking the string

see example:

```js
var content = '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        content += '<div class="parent">';
            content += '<div class="firstChild"></div>';
            content += '<div class="secondChild"></div>';
        content += '</div>';
    }
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Simplicity you can also try it this way

```
var content = '';

for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
    content += 
    '<div class="parent">' +
       '<div class="firstChild"></div>' +
       '<div class="secondChild"></div>' +
   '</div>';
}

$('.conainer').html(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
      var content = '';

      for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        content += "<div class='parent'>Parent";
          content += "<div class='firstChild'>firstChild</div>";
          content += "<div class='secondChild'>secondChild</div>";
        content += "</div>";
      }
      $('.conainer').html(content);
});
```

```css
.parent {
background: red;
}
.firstChild {
background: green;
}
.secondChild {
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conainer"></div>
```

Use ""s for string literals like that and use ' ' to escape.